# How to rate limit a node.js API that uses JWT?

Tags: node.js, api, devops, ddos

I have a node.js application that runs on different servers/containers. Clients are authenticated with JWT tokens. I want to protect this API from DDos attacks. User usage limit settings can be stored in the token. I've been thinking about som approaches:

- Increment counters in a memory database like redis or memcached and check it on every request. Could cause bottlenecks?.
- Do something in a nginx server (is it possible?)
- Use some cloud based solution (AWS WAF? Cloudfront? API Gateway? Do they do what I want?)

How to solve this?

Comment: `rate-limiter-flexible` helps with the first option https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible

Answer (score 1):

There are dedicated `npm` packages like

- `express-rate-limit` https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit
- `ratelimiter` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ratelimiter

I don't know about `AWS` but in `Azure` you can use `Azure API Management` to secure your api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts